# Unexpected padding in div when using html2pdf

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, html2pdf

I'm trying to convert my html to pdf in react using html2pdf library but for some reason, its inserting padding on its own to the divs in the downloaded pdf.
But when I'm using the same code in vanilla javascript, its working perfectly fine.

> Section with the issue

```
            <section
            className="relative w-full  bg-white"
            style={{ height: "236mm" }}
            >
            <div className=" flex w-full ">
                <div className=" w-full mx-5 ">
                <div className="  ">
                    <h1
                    className="titleq text-4xl tracking-widest whitespace-nowrap font-semibold mt-4 "
                    style={{ color: "#015E72" }}
                    >
                    Overview
                    </h1>
                    <p
                    className="  whitespace-nowrap font-semibold mt-2 mx-2 titlex"
                    style={{ fontSize: "medium" }}
                    >
                    {" "}
                    <span style={{ color: "#737373" }}>Itinerary for</span>{" "}
                    <span style={{ color: "#00B8C4" }}>5 Nights & 6 Days</span>{" "}
                    </p>
                    <div className=" flex gap-5 whitespace-nowrap text-xs mt-1 pb-3 mx-1 titlex">
                    <p>
                        {" "}
                        <span className=" font-semibold mx-1 ">Arrival:</span>
                        21/03/2024
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <span className=" font-semibold mx-1 ">Departure:</span>
                        3/26/2024
                    </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className=" parent flex gap-5 border-t-2 border-b-2  titlex">
                    <div
                    className="w-20  items-center flex justify-center  "
                    style={{ backgroundColor: "#015E72" }}
                    >
                    <h3 className=" "> Day 1 </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div className="days flex flex-col space-y-2 py-3">
                    <div className="flex items-center gap-5">
                        <table className="w-full">
                        <tr className="space-x-8">
                            <td className="font-semibold">Sightseeing</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td className="font-semibold">:</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td className="">Srinagar</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr className="space-x-8">
                            <td className="font-semibold">Hotel Stay At</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td className="font-semibold">:</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td className="">Home in Paradise</td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className=" parent flex gap-5 border-t-2 border-b-2  titlex">
                    <div
                    className="  w-20 text-center items-center flex justify-center  "
                    style={{ backgroundColor: "#D9F6FA" }}
                    >
                    <h3 className="   whitespace-nowrap  m-0 "> Day 2 </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div className="days flex flex-col space-y-2 py-3">
                    <div className="flex items-center gap-5">
                        <table className="w-full">
                        <tr className="space-x-8">
                            <td className="font-semibold">Sightseeing</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td className="font-semibold">:</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td className="">Sona,marg</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr className="space-x-8">
                            <td className="font-semibold">Hotel Stay At</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td className="font-semibold">:</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td className="">Home in Paradise</td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className=" parent flex gap-5 border-t-2 border-b-2  titlex">
                    <div
                    className="  w-20 text-center items-center flex justify-center  "
                    style={{ backgroundColor: "#015E72" }}
                    >
                    <h3 className="   whitespace-nowrap  m-0 "> Day 3 </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div className="days flex flex-col space-y-2 py-3">
                    <div className="flex items-center gap-5">
                        <table className="w-full">
                        <tr className="space-x-8">
                            <td className="font-semibold">Sightseeing</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td className="font-semibold">:</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td className="">Doodhpathri </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr className="space-x-8">
                            <td className="font-semibold">Hotel Stay At</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td className="font-semibold">:</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td className="">Home in Paradise</td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className=" parent flex gap-5 border-t-2 border-b-2  titlex">
                    <div
                    className="  w-20 text-center items-center flex justify-center  "
                    style={{ backgroundColor: "#D9F6FA" }}
                    >
                    <h3 className="   whitespace-nowrap  m-0 "> Day 4 </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div className="days flex flex-col space-y-2 py-3">
                    <div className="flex items-center gap-5">
                        <table className="w-full">
                        <tr className="space-x-8">
                            <td className="font-semibold">Sightseeing</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td className="font-semibold">:</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td className="">Gulmarg</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr className="space-x-8">
                            <td className="font-semibold">Hotel Stay At</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td className="font-semibold">:</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td className="">Zahgeer Continental</td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className=" parent flex gap-5 border-t-2 border-b-2  titlex">
                    <div
                    className="  w-20 text-center items-center flex justify-center  "
                    style={{ backgroundColor: "#015E72" }}
                    >
                    <h3 className="   whitespace-nowrap  m-0 "> Day 5 </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div className="days flex flex-col space-y-2 py-3">
                    <div className="flex items-center gap-5">
                        <table className="w-full">
                        <tr className="space-x-8">
                            <td className="font-semibold">Sightseeing</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td className="font-semibold">:</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td className="">Pahalgam</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr className="space-x-8">
                            <td className="font-semibold">Hotel Stay At</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td className="font-semibold">:</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td className="">Pahalgam Peaks</td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div className="   " style={{ width: "50%", height: "237mm" }}>
                <img
                    className="w-full h-full"
                    src=" https://tripdocks-images-bucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/Company/KAshmir%20DAsh%20%281%29.png?X-Amz-Expires=604800&response-content-type=image%2Fpng&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAR3BJ4BUYEYXQ5HPZ%2F20240213%2Fap-south-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20240213T151509Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=052c26dc33e359c5f3424f970873ebcced76cf7d4a8b181ca82c72405d747c74"
                    alt="  "
                    srcset="  "
                    style={{ objectFit: "cover", height: "220mm" }}
                />
                </div>

                <div className=" w-full absolute bottom-1">
                <div className="w-full flex">
                    <div className=" w-1/2 flex items-end ml-2">
                    <div className="">
                        <img
                        className="w-8 h-7"
                        src=" https://tripdocks-images-bucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/Company/Logo%20Crop_77a46fb1-ac8f-4856-a121-3054f3acbfed.png?X-Amz-Expires=604800&response-content-type=image%2Fpng&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAR3BJ4BUYEYXQ5HPZ%2F20240213%2Fap-south-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20240213T151509Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=3f19a9b10f257d7424045c439bd653ae52d9f0ddb0c3cfa8543517d83a6925c6"
                        crossorigin="anonymous"
                        alt=""
                        srcset=""
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className=" relative">
                        <p
                        className="font-semibold absolute bottom-0 whitespace-nowrap"
                        style={{ color: "#015d72cf", fontSize: "x-small" }}
                        >
                        <div>
                            <p>6005646020</p>
                            <p>Kashmir Dash Holidays</p>
                        </div>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className=" w-1/2 flex justify-end items-end">
                    <div className="flex justify-center items-center">
                        <img
                        className="w-5 h-5 "
                        src="https://emecbucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/test-images/logob.png"
                        alt=""
                        crossorigin="anonymous"
                        srcset=""
                        />
                        <p
                        className="font-semibold text-xs mr-5"
                        style={{ color: "#015d72cf" }}
                        >
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;Powered by TripDocks
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </section>
```

> Download PDF code

```
   const options = {
  filename: "Package Trial.pdf",

  html2canvas: { scale: 1.5, useCORS: true },
  jsPDF: {
    format: [236, 229], // Custom page size (height x width) in millimeters
    orientation: "portrait",
  },
  margin: [0, -2.2, -3, 0], // Adjust margins as needed
  pagebreak: { mode: "avoid-all" }, // Add page break between sections
};

html2pdf().set(options).from(printableRef.current).save();
```

[image: Actual Page]
**This is the Actual Page written**

[image: PDF Image]

**This is the pdf I get after downloading**

Comment: Might be a bug in `html2pdf`.

Comment: Hello Dawood, it is an issue with the library, and I found this discussion：https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/issues/689
I think it is the same issue

Comment: @AdamBasha thanks, it somewhat helped. We have to hard code the positions of the divs in this library for some reason.